# the address for the array pointer, &array

Tags: c

The following program prints that a and array share the same address.
How should I understand this behavior?
Is it &arr the address for the pointer arr, which contains the beginning address the 10 chars?

```js
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char arr[10] = {0};

    char* a = (char*)(&arr);

    *a = 1;

    printf("a=%p,arr=%p.\n", a, arr);
    printf("%d\n", arr[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `&arr` is the address of the first element of `arr`. Of course, `a` has the same value, because you assigned it that value in the first place.

Comment: @Alex: The first thing you have to learn is that there's no such thing as "pointer `arr`". `arr` array is array, not a pointer. There's no pointer of any kind there. There's massive amount of information properly explaining what an array is on the Net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you allocate an array in C, what you get is something like the following:

```
          +---+ 
  arr[0]: |   |
          +---+
  arr[1]: |   |
          +---+
           ...
          +---+
arr[N-1]: |   |
          +---+
```

That's it.  There's no separate memory location set aside for an object named `arr` to store the address of the first element of the array.  Thus, the address of the first element of the array (`&arr[0]`) is the same *value* as the address of the array itself (`&arr`).

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

So the type of the expression `arr` in the first `printf` call is `char [10]`; by the rule above, the expression "decays" to type `char *`, and the value is the address of `arr[0]`.

In the expression `&arr`, `arr` is the operand of the unary `&` operator, so the conversion isn't applied; instead of getting an expression of type `char **`, you get an expression of type `char (*)[10]` (pointer to 10-element array of `char`).  Again, since the address of the first element of the array is the same as the address of whole array, the expressions `arr` and `&arr` have the same *value*.

Answer (score 1):

In idiomatic C, you should write `char *a = arr;` or `char *a = &(arr[0]);`. `&arr` is normally a `char **`. Even if modern (C++) compilers fixe it automatically, it is not correct C.

As `arr` is an array of `char`, `arr[0]` is a `char` and arr is the same as `&(arr[0])` so it is a `char *`. It may be strange if you are used to other languages, but it is how C works. And it would be the same if arr was an array of any other type including `struct`.

Comment: `&arr` will be `char (*)[10]`, that is a pointer to an array of 10 `char`. @FrédéricHamidi

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi You may believe what you want, but what really counts is what the compiler will believe :-), I've editet my post to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The address printed out by `arr` and `a` is the memory address of the first element of the array `arr`. (Remember, the name of an array is always a pointer to the first element of that array.) This is because after you have defined the array `arr`, you define `a` as a pointer to the same address in memory.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
>   expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
>   element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
>   has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

The address of an array is the address of its first element. So though these types are different

`char ( * )[10]` ( that corresponds to &arr ) and `char *`(that is used in the casting in statement 
char* a = (char*)(&arr); ) they will have the same value that is the address of the first element of the array.

If you would not use the casting then the correct definition of the pointer initialized by expression &arr would be

```
char ( *a )[10] = &arr;
```

The difference is seen then the pointer is incremented. For your definition of pointer a the value of expression `++a` will be greater `sizeof( char)` than the initial value . For the pointer I showed the value of expression ++a will be greater `10 * sizeof( char )` than the initial value.

In your case the type of expression `*a` is `char` and you may write `*a = 1;` while in my case the type of expression `*a` will be `char[10]` and you may not write `*a = 1;`